# Получить данные с Vuex внутри validate()

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Всем привет.
Есть такой код:

```js
<template>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <HeaderApp>

      <DivHeaderMenu>
      </DivHeaderMenu>

    </HeaderApp>

    <CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp>
    </CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp>

    <FooterApp>
    </FooterApp>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
  //company_history
  import axios from 'axios';
  import HeaderApp from '~/components/HeaderApp';
  import FooterApp from '~/components/FooterApp';
  import CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp from '~/components/CenterContentDinamicFirmenistorieApp'
  import DivHeaderMenu from '~/components/DivHeaderMenu';
  import Pixelperfect from '~/components/Pixelperfect';

  export default{

  fetch ({ store, params }) {
    return axios.get('http://seo-gmbh.eu/json/api_sunds.php?action=get_pages&url=company_history')
    .then((res) => {
      store.commit('company_history/init_data_for_firmenistorie', res.data);
    })
  },


  validate(data) {

    console.log(this.$store.state.company_history.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieSortArrayData);

    return true;

  },
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

При потытке внутри `validate()` получить данные из Vuex хранилища - возникает проблема.(данные не найдены.)
Вопрос:
Какие варианты могут быть в плане решения, если учесть, что со стороны хранилища проблема исключена.
(и в дату такой же точно параметр прилетает без ошибки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функцию [`validate`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-validate) первым параметром передается [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) и с помощью [деструктуризации объекта](http://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment#destrukturizatsiya-obekta) [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context) можно получить [`store`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#-code-store-code-a-href-https-vuex-vuejs-org-en-api-html-vuexstore-instance-properties-em-vuex-store-em-a-) & [`params`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#-code-params-code-em-object-em-)

```js
validate({ store, params }) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(store.state.company_history.dbFirmenstorie.dbFirmenistorieSortArrayData);

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(params);

  return true;
}
```

Comment: А если мне необходимо что бы в validate так же передавалась в параметр data(помимо store) - это можно реализовать?
Имею ввиду что бы я мог вытащить значение урла с помощью data.params.id и потом сравнить его с данными из vuex.

Comment: @MikeKharkov в контексте так же есть объекты `params` & `query`, я обновил ответ

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAxpx8oHZkd0PA
а если у меня с хранилищем есть асинхронные проблемы - и данные через раз то приходят то нет(речь о validate) - что можно придумать в таком случае?
+ иногда почему то прилетает сразу 2 ответа и пустой массив и с правильным значением: http://joxi.ru/gmv1nyvHqX7D0r

Comment: и еще вопрос - могу ли я сделать редирект внутри validate на любую страницу если пользователь ввел 404-й урл?

Comment: @MikeKharkov по `store` необходимо больше данных, чтобы понять что за асинхронные проблемы, функция `validate` может быть как синхронной так и асинхронной. По поводу редиректа, в `context` еще есть 2 функции `redirect` & `error`, которые могут помочь. https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#-code-redirect-code-em-function-em- https://nuxtjs.org/api/context#-code-error-code-em-function-em-

Comment: а каков порядок действий должен быть при работе с error и redirect параметрами?
Че то я попробовал пока у меня не очень получается.

на счет проблемы с асинхронностью и Vuex - то я имел ввиду что вот эти данные(именно внутри Validate) через раз - то удается получать то нет:
В обычных компонентах нет никаких проблем их получить.
http://joxi.ru/J2bxbPVc0QVZGr

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAxpx8oHZ7K39A
пока что - что бы заработал редирект я нашел только вот такое извращенское решение )

Comment: И еще вопрос:
http://joxi.ru/12MgEPYhlDwXqr
если я добавляю вот такие символы в адресную строку - то у меня происходит редирект.
Но если я добавляю символы после слеша:
http://joxi.ru/BA0QjX0IMevVJr
То редиректа не происходит и выдается 404-я ошибка.
Почему это происходит?

Comment: + если я прописываю статус код какой попало - то все равно происходит редирект - почему?
http://joxi.ru/KAg5e6oHEwNaam

Comment: @MikeKharkov 404 ошибка возникает, если не был найдет роут, либо если была "вызвана" 404 ошибка, редирект должен работать без `error`

Если у вас есть конкретная проблема или вопрос - то задайте его путем создания нового вопроса

Comment: http://joxi.ru/brRgJP5h7jnOem
но у меня не работает редирект без error или с error в случае если в урл добавлена дополнительная вложенность после слеша:
http://joxi.ru/vAWWbPKIgbVOPA
+ проблема получения данные с хранилища осталась и я обьяснил ее детали и это соотвествует названию поста.